# authenticating mongodb from a remote machine with ssh tunnelling

Tags: java, linux, mongodb, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I have mongo db running in a remote server (debian) with authentication on. I need to connect to it with UMongo (UI tool for mongodb) from my local machine (windows) to visualize the data. I have not opened mongodb port in server machine, but have made a ssh tunnel from my `localhost:9999` to the `mongodb-host:port`. As connection uri in UMongo, i have given

```
[username]:[password]@localhost:9002
(also tried with [username]:[password]@localhost:9002/dbname)
```

and tried to connect. It shows the database but doesn't authenticate, it throws authentication error. I have made sure that the credentials given are correct. Wondering whether the credentials are not being passed to the mongodb server properly with ssh tunnelling.

**Update**: I restarted mongo server with authentication disabled. After that i tried to access the remote mongo shell. When i tried with `mongo --port 9002`, it gave the below error:

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.4
connecting to: 127.0.0.1:9002/test
Thu Sep 05 22:55:21.107 Socket recv() errno:10054 An existing connection was forcibly
  closed by the remote host. 127.0.0.1:9002
Thu Sep 05 22:55:21.107 SocketException: remote: 127.0.0.1:9002 error: 9001 socket 
exception [1] server [127.0.0.1:9002]
Thu Sep 05 22:55:21.107 DBClientCursor::init call() failed
Thu Sep 05 22:55:21.107 JavaScript execution failed: Error: DBClientBase::findN:   
transport error: 127.0.0.1:9002 ns: admin.$cmd query: { whatsmyuri: 1
} at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:L114
exception: connect failed
```

But when i tried with `mongo --port 9002 --nodb`, i was able to get the mongo shell. Then i tried to `use mydb` which throws the below error:

```
Thu Sep 05 22:57:43.205 JavaScript execution failed: ReferenceError: db is not defined 
at src/mongo/shell/utils.js:L691
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Is it likely it's using a different port for login?

Comment: Maybe a better fit on ServerFault.

Comment: Can you authenticate to the database using the mongo shell?